# Can you use your own GIS shapefiles in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-earth, dashboard, gis

I am considering using Google Data Studio as part of an online dashboard, but I need the dashboard to show geographic data against my own customized regional areas. Can I pull in a GIS file such as a shape file, KMZ, etc. to do this with Google Data Studio?